# how to work with html resources in a blackberry-eclipse application?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am a beginner in **blackberry** app development.

I had installed the **blackberry** plugin in **eclipse** successfully. my first app needs to load html files from a folder I had created named **"assets"** inside my project. so how can I load the html file **"assets/index.html"**?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
    // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
    Ramadanclass theApp = new Ramadanclass();       
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}
```

mainscreen:

```
public final class Ramadan extends MainScreen
{ 

    public Ramadan()
    {                   
        setTitle("Ramadan");    
    }
}
```

**Edit:** what I tried:

```
BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField(); 
add(myBrowserField); 
myBrowserField.requestContent("assets/index.html");
```

which had this error

> no navigation request handler for assets/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by "call". Do you want to access its contents, or display it?

Comment: i want to display html page

Comment: You can use the `BrowserField`, its `displayContent` method can take your html as an argument. I don't want to post an answer now though, too busy to actually try it atm.

Comment: BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField();
            add(myBrowserField);
            myBrowserField.requestContent("assets/index.html");  i had this error "no navigation request handler  for assets/index.html

Comment: You have to add the appropriate prefix to the path. `http:///` for interwebs, `file:///` for a local file, etc.

Comment: i had blank page      BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
            config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_CARET);
            BrowserField test = new BrowserField(config);
            test.requestContent("file:///assets/index.html");

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Display_HTML_from_a_resource_within_your_app_825672_11.jsp

This should help, look at step 6 and the note after it. I was surprised

Comment: sorry i had this error local:///index.html resource not found

Comment: The only thing i can think of is trying with your html in a different folder, such as src or res

Comment: error file:///res/index.html:<br><br>file system error {1003}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the link that @Turdnugget supplied](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Display_HTML_from_a_resource_within_your_app_825672_11.jsp) says:

> The BrowserField class does not access resources using a folder structure. The BrowserField class displays the first resource found that matches the specifed file name.

That means that even if you put index.html into an `assets` folder, the BlackBerry build process and/or runtime will *flatten out* (i.e. ignore) your directory structure and therefore you'll have to load the html file with:

```java
myBrowserField.requestContent("local:///index.html");
```

As you can imagine, this works ok if you only have one file named `index.html` in your project, but if you have two files with that name, in different folders, the browser field may not load the one you want.  I have projects where I do have different versions of html files that are loaded depending on the device, or the version of the app (full vs. free).  So, I like to be able to store my html resources in different folders.

To accomplish this, I've used the following code with `BrowserField`:

```java
  browser = new BrowserField();
  add(browser);

  InputStream content = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resourcesWeb/index.html");     
  try {
     byte[] html = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(content);
     browser.displayContent(new String(html), "http://localhost");
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

For this to work, I store the file `index.html` in a folder named `resourcesWeb` (name it whatever you like), and that folder is located inside the top-level `res` folder.

Note that this is not Android.  There is not normally an `assets` directory.  When you use the BlackBerry Eclipse plug-in to create a new project, it creates a `src` and a `res` folder for you.  I would use that.  Create a new project if you need to.  Then, keep all non-source code resources (html, xml, images, etc.) somewhere under the `res` folder.

If you didn't create your project this way, you may find that your app is built without including the `assets` folder you created.  You can *probably* fix this by right clicking on your project in Eclipse, and selecting **Properties**.  You can add the `assets` folder to the Build Path using this dialog:

[image]

and notice that `assets` should show up in the **Order and Export** tab as well.

However, I think it's easiest just to create and use projects the way the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin wants to.  This will also make your projects more familiar to other BlackBerry Java developers that see your code.  In my opinion, you should save Android naming conventions for Android projects.